# Time out in read_some()

Tags: c++, timeout, boost-asio, tcpclient

Im building a TCP client based on Boost::ASIO lib. I used `read_some()` from Boost to read the response from the server. I want to implement a time out logic in it, which send a "ping" command if there has been no communication for 10 seconds. The problem is

```
l=_socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(this->reply,sizeof(this->reply)),error);
```

seems to block the program execution when there is no data to be transferred to the read buffer. So is there any way out of it? I didn't want to use the `async_read_some()` as I need this thread to sleep if there is no data has been transferred in to the buffer, that was easily done in `read_some()` as it returns the size of data transferred.
The main thing is even during time-out I dont want to close the connection, but to check if the server responds to a ping command, if it doesn't I would move to re-connection. So this is more or less checking if the server is still there connected, when no data is transmitted over a time period.

Comment: If you could clarify why you are averse to using `async_read_some()` this might not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: A synchronous blocking read with timeout can be implemented via an asynchronous read, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858719).  For non-blocking without a timeout, Boost.Asio sockets can be made synchronous non-blocking via [`socket::non_blocking()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/non_blocking/overload2.html).

Comment: @SamMiller I dont want to use async_read_some() because my read thread check if the length of the message is greater than zero, if so data handler is called else the thread sleeps, I couldn't implement this with async_read_some(). If there is any way to do that I will be happy to change by the way.

Comment: @Jishnu U Nair threads and sleepings sound like an incorrect approach. Did you take a look at asio examples?