# deadline_timer waits only one time

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

i have implemented a pretty standard emulation of blocking api with timeouts for boost::asio. this is my main cycle:

```
io_service io_svc;
tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_port);
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_svc, endpoint);

accept_helper acc_hlpr(acceptor, 5000);

while (m_bStop == false)
{
  tcp::socket socket(io_svc);

  if (acc_hlpr.accept(socket))
  {
    // do stuff

    socket.close();
  }
}
```

this is the helper class

```
class accept_helper
{
public:
  accept_helper (tcp::acceptor &acc, size_t msTO) : m_timer(acc.get_io_service()), m_acceptor(acc), m_msTO(msTO) { }

  bool accept (tcp::socket &socket)
  {
    m_bTimeout = false;
    m_bAccept = false;

    m_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(m_msTO));
    m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&accept_helper::handle_timeout, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    m_acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&accept_helper::handle_accept, this));  

    m_timer.get_io_service().run_one();
    m_timer.get_io_service().reset();

    if (m_bAccept)
    {
      m_timer.cancel();
      return true;
    }
    else if (m_bTimeout)
    {
      // BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO is defined
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      m_acceptor.cancel(ec);
    }

    return false;
  }

private:
  void          handle_accept (void)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
    m_bAccept = true;
  }

  void          handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code & error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
      m_bTimeout = true;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timer;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor &m_acceptor;
  boost::mutex m_mutex;
  size_t m_msTO;
  bool m_bTimeout;
  bool m_bAccept;
};
```

the problem is that timer waits only on the first iteration. on others run_one method just returns immediately and no flags are set. i have tried to make timer local, but that didn't help. how to make timer wait every time?

fixed version

```
bool accept (tcp::socket &socket)
  {
    m_bTimeout = false;
    m_bAccept = false;

    m_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(m_msTO));
    m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&accept_helper::handle_timeout, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    m_acceptor.async_accept(socket, boost::bind(&accept_helper::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));    

    m_timer.get_io_service().reset();
    m_timer.get_io_service().run_one();

    if (m_bAccept)
    {
      m_timer.cancel();
    }
    else if (m_bTimeout)
    {
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      m_acceptor.cancel(ec);
    }

    while (m_timer.get_io_service().run_one());

    return m_bAccept;
  }

private:
  void          handle_accept (const boost::system::error_code & error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
      m_bAccept = true;
    }
  }

  void          handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code & error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
      m_bTimeout = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) function only allows the `io_service` to resume running from a stopped state; it does not remove any handlers already queued into the `io_service`.  In this case, two operations are initiated on the `io_service` (`async_wait` and `async_accept`), but only one handler is executed, as the `io_service`'s event loop is being processed by [`io_service::run_one()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one/overload1.html).  Upon the next call to `accept_helper::accept()`, a handler from the previous invocation will be executed.

To resolve this, consider running the `io_service` until both handlers have been invoked.  Some solutions will run the `io_service` to completion, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868051/1053968) and the Boost.Asio [blocking tcp client timeout example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp).

Comment: it works now, thanks. i've updated the post with fixed version, is it ok, to use it like that?

Comment: @Sergi0: Yup, looks fine as long as the `io_service` is only being used for those two operations.  Otherwise, you'd want to update state in the completion handlers, and check for the state within the while-loop body to determine if the handlers have been executed.